# Javascript - check if key is not in data

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a function that let's me know if my key is in my data or not.

```js
data = [{
  "1" : ["1007","1020"],
  "2" : ["1200","1493"],
  "3" : ["6754","8652"],
}]

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
    var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var key in data[i])
        {
            if (key in data[i]) {
                if (data[i][key].indexOf(value) !== -1){
                    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = key;

                } 
            }

        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
<input id="input" />
```

What this code does is that he checks if the number insered in the input is in data and displays his group number  into the div. But what if the number is not in the data ? I want to be able to display it as '0' in the div if the number doesn't exist in my data.

Comment: `var jayIFoundOne = false;` before the loop, when you find one you set it to true inside the loop (and break out of the loop, if you don't expect more than one match) ... and then you can simply check that flag afterwards.

Comment: you can use a flag initialized as false, if you found it toggle it to true, if after you are done looping through the array the flag is still false - then display 0 in your div

Comment: @CBroe hmm, I can't visualize it, can you give me an example ?

Comment: so if you find a match why do you keep on looping?

Comment: @epascarello because if the user changes it again out of a mistake, the value wouldn't change.

Comment: No, that is not what I am walking about. I am saying that you loop and find a match, than you keep on looping to see if there is a match. You should stop after you found a match, unless you want the last index that has a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
data = [{
  "1" : ["1007","1020"],
  "2" : ["1200","1493"],
  "3" : ["6754","8652"],
}]

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
    var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var foundIt = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length && !foundIt; i++) {
        for (var key in data[i])
        {
            if (key in data[i]) {
                if (data[i][key].indexOf(value) !== -1){
                    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = key;
                    foundIt = true;

                } 
            }

        }
        if (!foundIt) {
            document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
<input id="input" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following optimized  version:

```js
data = [{
  "1" : ["1007","1020"],
  "2" : ["1200","1493"],
  "3" : ["6754","8652"],
}]

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);
function myFunction(el) {
    var value = el.target.value, obj = data[0], keys, key = 0;
    if (value) {
     keys = Object.keys(obj);
        keys.forEach(function(k){
          if (obj[k].indexOf(value) !== -1) key = k;
        });
     document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = key;
    }    
}
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
<input id="input" />
```